# Camera data Intent is null

Tags: java, android

I saw other questions and answers about this problem, But none of them worked for me.

I'm trying to take a picture from camera and show it inside an imageview.
and also I'm using a Helper class for having a cleaner code.

here are the codes in Helper class:

taking picture:

```
public static void getphoto(final Activity act, final int int, final Uri uri){

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);  
act.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, int);

        }
```

getting filpath:

```
    public static String pathgal(Activity act, Uri uri){

    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    return filePath;
    }
    return null;

}
```

getting result:

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String capturedImageFilePath = Helper.pathgal(act, mCapturedImageURI);
            bmp = Helper.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);

            Log.d("******CAMERAAAAAAA*******", "Camera fine 10");

            if(data != null)
            {
                Log.d("******CAMERAAAAAAA*******", "Camera fine 11");

                Helper.showpic(act, id1, bmp);

                Log.d("******CAMERAAAAAAA*******", "Camera fine 12");

            } else if (data == null) {
                Log.d("******CAMERAAAAAAA*******", "Camera fine 13");
                Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(), "Data is Null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

}
```

now if I test this on a low level cell phone (like HTC wildfire s), everything works just fine and I get "camera fine 11 and 12" Logs. But if I test it on a High level cell phone (like Galaxy s4), it gives me "Data is null" and "camera fine 13".

so how should I prevent getting null in that kind of devices?

Comment: What is data?  Where is it set?

Comment: it's an Intent. Android Name it automatically in onActivityResult.

Comment: Ah you mean the third parameter of onActivityResult(int, int, Intent).  Android doesn't control what you name the parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing  the extra parameter MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT with uri in the camera intent, you are telling camera activity to write the captured image to that path and it will not return the bitmap in the onActivityResult method. So That you are getting null on onActivityResult.

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri); //this line
```

You may rather try this

```
String capturedImageFilePath = Helper.pathgal(act, mCapturedImageURI);
        bmp = Helper.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);
if(bmp != null)
  {
    Helper.showpic(act, id1, bmp);
  } else{
      Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(), "bmp is Null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: yes, you are right. now I give "bitmap exceeds vm buget" error which is a another question. thanks bro.